Azure global endpoint error from Quarkus rest client
I have a Quarkus rest client interface from which I am trying to make a call to azure global endpoint for provisioning and registering the device. However am getting 404 error as the parameters and values getting injected looks correct and so as the path to the endpoint but still not sure why am getting 404. Here is the documentation to the azure endpoint am referring to make a call from the my client for registering the device by passing the group enrollment id into the payload -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/device/runtime-registration/register-device?view=rest-iot-dps-device-2021-10-01#deviceregistration. For authorization, am using generating the SAS token. Am I missing anything from the documentation or this document is outdated?
import jakarta.ws.rs.*;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "dps-api")
@Path("/registrations")
public interface AzureRestClient {

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{registrationId}/register?api-version=2021-10-01")
    Response registerDevice(RegistrationPayload payload, @PathParam("registrationId") String registrationId,
            @HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization);

}

application.properties
quarkus.rest-client.dps-api.url=https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/0usxxxxxxx
Error
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.ClientWebApplicationException: Received: 'Not Found, status code 404' when invoking REST Client method: 'com.my.clients.AzureRestClient#registerDevice'
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.RestClientRequestContext.unwrapException(RestClientRequestContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.handleException(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:331)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:175)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.RestClientRequestContext$1.lambda$execute$0(RestClientRequestContext.java:324)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:270)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:252)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.lambda$runOnContext$0(ContextInternal.java:50)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    ... 2 more


You need to either provide the idScope on the @Path of the interface.
Or when it is a constant, in application.props:
idScope=${ID_SCOPE:123456}
quarkus.rest-client.dps-api.url=https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/${idScope}
Anyways, 404 indicates that your url is wrong.

I am actually hardcoding the ${idScope} in my applicaiton.properties, though did not update  above in details just updated it with sample. With that I am still getting 404 even having idScope
quarkus.rest-client.dps-api.url=https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/0usxxxxxxx

Did you also check that your queryParams are sent ? Because you have hardcoded that in the @Path and that’s normally not how you would do that.

Are you referring to this query param that is the version -> api-version=2021-10-01?

Yes I tried with @QueryParam still getting 404

Can you try it with @ClientQueryParam on the method ? See also this link and can you log your request ? Add quarkus.rest-client.logging.scope=all to app.props

It not worked with that either. I am wondering if this is something to do with my Sas token? I mean in some post seeing bearer token is being used and some suggest Sas token.

I should be using not the commercial cloud but .us one which I just updated the url to https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.us and now getting 400 that is weird
